# Adjust refine accuracy settings for Search Results web part

Tags: 2013, search-results

got what I think is a quick question...

I have a 'Search Results' web part which queries and return people results from MySites.

There are +/- 500 people that get returned, and my web part is placed on a page which is designed to serve people in various departments.

The idea here, is that each webpart on each site collection will refine the people results based on the Departments property.

So, for instance, this is what I see when I choose to refine the results via the query editor..

[image]

The thing is, I have results/people that have Department values which do not show up in the selection.

Did a little investigating, and it seems that there is a 'Refine Accuracy' setting which determines how many results it scans in order to produce the amount of Refine options.

This is a video where this setting is discussed in SP 2010 -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYDfvJsMzzE

By default, I believe, it is set to 50. So if my person who has a unique Department value is in the 200-300 range, I wont see his Department value as a refinable option.

However, I cant seem to find this setting for my web part, and not sure if it is anywhere else I can set this...

does anybody perhaps know?

Thanks!

---

As I work around I found that actually entering the refine value in the query editor box works (ie, adding `Department="Marketing"`). Would be nice though to tell the clients they can use the refiner list as a more user friendly option)