# Search Results Web Part Refiner issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, refiner, search-schema

I have a SharePoint 2013 On Prem Farm.

On the Intranet Site is a Subsite of Departments. On each sub site is a page called Team Members. All members of the department are displayed using a Search Result Web Part, which refines on the users Department which it gets from their User Profile.

I recently created a new Department sub site and Team Members Page but when I try to add the Team Members to the page the new department is not displayed as an option for the refiner.

[image]

The New Department has been added to the Term Set and a Full Crawl has been run. Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks Dan

Comment: Do you have any items using the new department name? If not that may be the reason why you don't see it.

Comment: Marek, thanks for the quick response - I'll take a look -Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marek, I checked and there was Content so it was not that. To resolve this issue I followed this link [Adjust refine accuracy settings for Search Results web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160064/adjust-refine-accuracy-settings-for-search-results-web-part?rq=1)

I know links are not to be trusted to last so here is what I did to resolve/work around my issue.

In the Build a Query box I clicked on the 'Basics' Tab.
In the area marked Query Text was the following text :-

path:"http://myprofile"{SearchBoxQuery}

To this I added the following to read  :-

path:"http://myprofile"{SearchBoxQuery}Department="newdepartmentname"
where newdpartmentname is the name of the Department that was missing from the list of Refiners.  NOTE - the double quotes around the department name are required.

Clicked on Test Query and the Search Result Preview displayed the correct result. Applied and saved the Webpart

There is probably a more permanent fix I could have applied but this will do for now and get the client off my back. I hope others find this useful......Dan.