# Refiners missing in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, people-search

Last year I asked a question about Search Results Web part refiners here : -
[Search Results Web Part Refiner issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/search-results-web-part-refiner-issue)

I was offered a Solution and it worked. Thanks.

However, now the Client is reporting another issue. On investigation I have discovered that there are no refiners at all to choose from. They are all gone.

[image]

[image]

Investigation lead me to believe this is a Search issue and upon inspection of the Search I came across an error due to a password change of the Managed Account

[image]

'The Item was not crawled because of a password change'

I've followed the wisdom on Google and re-applied the Password to the Search Account. I've made sure the Account has Read access to the WebApp and it still only crawls the Top Level and nothing underneath

[image]

I've checked the Content Source and it has 2 URL's in there to Search. It searches the top URL fine but only the top level of the second.

So my question, is how do I get my refiners back ? Am I on the right track with Search or have I missed something entirely.
All answers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After you update the password of the Managed Account, What is the error message displayed in the crawl log?

Reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25749.item-was-not-crawled-because-of-a-password-change-update-password-and-retry-crawling.aspx

Comment: The error message is the same in the crawl log as before - Item was not crawled because of a password change. Update password and retry crawling. It's as though the password change is not being recognised.... or it's not using the account in Search Admin